# Нарисовать простую шахматную доску php

Tags: php, html

Вот так я реализую свою доску(с инпутов берутся значения-размеры доски), но я не знаю как мне сделать вывод этой доски на экран, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form  method="get">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="height">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="width">
    </p>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<table border='1' id="chessBoard"></table>
<?php   

$table = '';
$width  = $_GET['width'];
$height = $_GET['height'];

for ($i = 1; $i <= $width ; $i++) { 
    $table += '<tr>';
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $height ; $j++) { 
        $color = ($i + $j) % 2 ? 'white' : 'black';
        $table += '<td bgcolor="' . $color . '" width="20"
        height="20"></td>'; 
    }
    $table += '</tr>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так например.

```
<table border='1' id="chessBoard">
<?php   

$table = '';
$width  = intval($_GET['width']);
$height = intval($_GET['height']);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $width ; $i++) { 
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $height ; $j++) { 
        $color = ($i + $j) % 2 ? 'white' : 'black';
        $table .= "<td bgcolor='{$color}' width='20' height='20'></td>"; 
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
echo $table;
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Необязательно это делать на `php`. Могу выдать `pure javascript` решение

Comment: Cпасибо, но нужно именно на php.

Comment: См. мой ответ, только что дополнил

Comment: Обратите внимание: конкатенация строк в современных(5+ что ли) `php` делается знаком `.`. Знак `+` устарел для этой задачи.

Comment: Cпасибо большое, всё получилось)

Answer (score 1):

Знаю, что код не оптимальный, заранее извиняюсь. Код был написан для реализации следующего примера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="400px" cellspacing="1px" cellpadding="0px" border="0px">
        <?php 
            $aplhabet = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H","H", "G", "F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A");
            $numbers = array("1", "8", "2", "7", "3", "6", "4", "5", "5", "4", "6", "3", "7", "2", "8", "1");
            $alpha = -1;
            $nums = -1;

            for($row=0;$row<10;$row++)
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                for($col=0;$col<10;$col++)
                {
                    if($row==0 or $row==9)
                    {
                        if($col==0 or $col==9){
                            echo "<td height=25px width=25px bgcolor=#686868></td>";
                        }
                        else{
                            $alpha++;
                            echo "<td height=25px width=25px bgcolor=#686868 align='center'>$aplhabet[$alpha]</td>";
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if(($row>= 1 and $row<9) and ($col==0 or $col==9)){
                            $nums++;
                            echo "<td height=25px width=25px bgcolor=#686868 align='center'>$numbers[$nums]</td>";
                        }
                        elseif($row%2 != 0) {
                            if($col%2 != 0){
                                echo "<td height=40px width=40px bgcolor=#FFFFFF></td>";
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "<td height=40px width=40px bgcolor=#000000></td>";
                            }
                        }
                        elseif($row%2 == 0){
                            if($col%2 == 0){
                                echo "<td height=40px width=40px bgcolor=#FFFFFF></td>";
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "<td height=40px width=40px bgcolor=#000000></td>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }






        ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```